# Angular HTML type inference is not working as i wanted

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Inside Angular component
I would like to grab div element by id or class

**This Works**

```
menuDisplayDiv  = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class")[0] as HTMLDivElement;
menuDisplayDiv  = document.getElementById("some_Id") as HTMLDivElement;
menuDisplayDiv  = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class")[0] as HTMLDElement;
menuDisplayDiv  = document.getElementById("some_Id") as HTMLElement;
menuDisplayDiv: HTMLElement  = document.getElementById("some_Id");
```

**This Does not works**

```
menuDisplayDiv: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class")[0]; 
menuDisplayDiv: HTMLElement  = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class")[0];    
menuDisplayDiv: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementById("some_Id");
```

ERROR in src/app/action-button-plugin/action-button-plugin.component.ts:62:11 - error TS2741: Property 'align' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLDivElement'.

```
62       let menuDisplayDiv: HTMLDivElement  = document.getElementById("menu01") ;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:6546:5
    6546     align: string;
             ~~~~~
    'align' is declared here.
```

> or shows

ERROR in src/app/action-button-plugin/action-button-plugin.component.ts:63:11 - error TS2740: Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, and 107 more.

> Please someone explain,Thank you with advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this statement:

```
menuDisplayDiv  = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class")[0] as HTMLDivElement;
```

On the right hand side, you are doing type casting, hence it is working.

For this statement:

```
menuDisplayDiv: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class")[0];
```

The variable type on the left hand side is specified to HTMLDivElement whereas the value on the right hand side if a more generic type hence it gives you an error.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit of a hidden snake in the grass, the 1st example is not a strict case of the element to an HTMLDivElement, it just tries to do the work with no complaint.  The 2nd example is a true cast and it finds missing properties.  It shouldn't happen but it does. This means the 'as' operator has different functionality.

Comment: The 'as' is used for typecasting.

Comment: Which one should i use? 'as' or ':' or both?

Comment: why this line worked `menuDisplayDiv: HTMLDivElement  = document.getElementById("some_Id");` but when i grab same using class shows error

Comment: Whether an assignment operation works or not depends upon the type specified in the left-hand side and the right-hand side. If you have specified something on the left-hand side, the return type on the right-hand side should be of the same type or a child of the type mentioned in the left hand side. I suggest you try out some examples in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/# for better understanding.